# Extract node value by calculating absolute position

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

My source XML looks:

```
  <test>
         <text1>Test</text1>
         <text2>Test</text2>
         <text2>Test</text2>
     <section>
         <text1>Test<bold>content</bold></text1>
         <text1>Test</text1>
         <text2>Test</text2>
         <text2>Test</text2>
     </section>
  </test>
```

Want to extract the value of 6th node, based on the absolute number of the element (overall count). The absolute number of the element has been identified using `<xsl:number level="any" from="/" count="*"/>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This xslt

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
        <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

        <xsl:variable name="allElements" select="//element()" />

        <xsl:template match="/">
            <output>
                <xsl:value-of select="$allElements[6]" />
            </output>
        </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

will result in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>Testcontent</output>
```

Comment: Hi Jirka, is it possible to extract the element value based on the absolute number using xpath expression??

Comment: I'm not sure because `position()` is evaluated in actual context (may be I'm wrong). But I made an experiment and it seems to be working without variable declaration. Try something like this `<xsl:value-of select="(//element())[6]" />`

Answer (score 2):

The XPath expression `/descendant::*[6]` should give you the element you need.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="/descendant::*[6]" />
</xsl:template>
```

outputs

```
<text1>Test<bold>content</bold></text1>
```

Note that this is an example of the difference between `descendant::` and `//` - `//*[6]` would give you all elements that are the sixth child element of their respective parent, rather than simply the sixth element in the document in depth-first order.